# remove TAG/TAA/TGA

Tags: text-processing, bioinformatics

I have a file in below mentioned format. I have to delete stop codons (TAG/TAA/TGA) anything that matches TAG or TAA or TGA. the search should be in multiples of three. (like it has to search every three letters and if it find stops codons those should be discarded  **atg** **ccc** **tca** **aga** ). I have searched different forms to remove the stop codons but wasn't it successful. appreciate you time. thank you

input.fa

```
3 1896    
FOMPING00005383   atgccctcaagacagccggggatgcctccgctggcgcctgggcttcaattcagcccaaaggccagccacggtcagcccacgtcggaagcccatcttccagccattgggtccgccgccgtcgacgtctattcatttgtcacagaagatgcaatcgcgctggggccggcaagctccgtctcacccgaaaatattgtcatgacacaacctaccactatacatcatgactctgtgaaaggcgagaagtttaccgttgagcgagacagcgtcgacgcgctctccttcagctcgaaccagagcgttccccggcc------taagttacccttaccttggcaagtattgatagcggccttgacctgtttgtgtactttcggcaaccactggtcgaat---------------------accaccatcattaaagagacgcatatcaacaactcccaattcgccaccttg------------------
```

Comment: Is that fasta file really correctly formatted? No header with `>`?

Comment: its in Phylip format

Comment: What do you mean by "discarded **atg** **ccc** **tca** **aga**"?

Comment: Just to make sure I'm not going crazy: Does this sequence in fact contain any in-frame stop codons? I have a feeling it doesn't.

Comment: @SatoKatsura i just gave it as example to search in every three letters (codons)

Comment: @Kusalananda files that i am working on has in-frame stop codons. i haven't cross checked if the example i posted has any in-frame stop codons

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while ( my $line = <> ) {
    chomp($line);

    if ($line =~ /\d+\s+\d+/) {
        printf("%s\n", $line);
        next;
    }

    my ( $head, $seq ) = split( /\s+/, $line );

    my $newseq;

    while ( $seq =~ /(...)/g ) {
        if ( $1 !~ /tag|taa|tga/ ) {
            $newseq .= $1;
        }
    }

    printf("%s   %s\n", $head, $newseq);
}
```

Running it:

```
$ ./script input.fa >output.fa
```

Assumptions and limitations:

1. The file is in "sequential format" as described here: http://evolution.genetics.washington.edu/phylip/doc/sequence.html
2. There are no spaces in the sequence.
3. The complete sequence length is a multiple of three (otherwise, the last incomplete codon will be left out of the output).
4. The sequence is not broken into multiple lines.

Mode of operation:

1. A line is read.
2. If it contains two integers, assume that it's the "header line" and output it.
3. Split the line on space characters into `$head` (the first bit of the line) and `$seq` (sequence).
4. Walk through the sequence three bases at a time.
5. If the current three bases matches a stop codon, they will not be put into the new sequence (`$newseq`), otherwise they will be.
6. Output the head-bit of the line together with the new sequence.
7. Continue with next line, if present.

To get a visual indication of the found stop codons, change the loop to

```
while ( $seq =~ /(...)/g ) {
    if ( $1 !~ /tag|taa|tga/ ) {
        $newseq .= $1;
    }
    else {
        $newseq .= "<STP>";
    }
}
```

Comment: the script worked fine, for some reason after the ID FOMPING00005383 it leaves single white space, but he the programme that i am using identifies as error. it should have 2 or more white spaces after the ID like in Input file: error of program **Error in sequence data file: F at 3997 seq 1.
Make sure to separate the sequence from its name by 2 or more spaces.**

Comment: @kapr0001 It's just a matter of inserting a couple of more spaces in the last `printf` statement. I have updated the answer. Sorry, I'm not entirely familiar with the Phylip format...

Comment: thank you, but for some reason in get he same error. but not for the original file that has two white spaces after the ID

Comment: @kapr0001 The data that you posted has three spaces, so that what I changed it to earlier today. If you want two space, change it to two spaces. Verify that you are working on the correct files. Does any sequence name contain a space? That will also mess things up. I wrote the code for the data provided, only.